# Which test should be believed about multivariate random variables, significant coefficients or multivariate normal tests?

Tags: time-series, statistical-significance, multivariate-analysis, descriptive-statistics

**Context:** I have an observed data set, denote it by data set $A$. I simulated a multivariate normal data set, denote it as data set $B$.

When I plot the ACF and PACF of both data sets I received a very similar result. I applied all joint test of multivariate normal test on the data set $A$, and I accepted that the null hence the data originate from a multivariate normal distribution.

However, when I fit a VAR model for each of both data set, I receive significant lag coefficients for data set $A$ but not for $B$.

**Question:** Does this mean that data set $A$ follows a multivariate normal?

**Context:** I am trying to understand what is the generating process of my observed sample, understanding this I need to apply different things at least to classify it. For example whether they are time dependent or not.

I have two return series equity and bond observed series for a certain country. I only have 108 data points. I did normality tests using Royston test and accepted that they follow a joint Gaussian distribution. When I fit a VAR(1) model on my dataset, I see that some of the coefficients are significant and this means that they are time dependent. I am not sure whether they are or not time dependent.

Comment: A multivariate distribution is not necessarily a time series.  So why are you computing autocorrelation and partial autocorrelation functions? I also do not understand the value of generating a simulated data set.

Comment: @MichaelChernick thank you very much for your add-on; I am trying to understand what is the generating process of my observed sample, understanding this I need to apply different things at least to classify it. For example are they time dependent or not

Comment: Can you describe your data for us?

Comment: @MichaelChernick I have two return series equity and bond observed series for a certain country. I only have 108 data points. I did normality tests using Royston test and accepted that they follow a joint Gaussian distribution. When I fit a VAR(1) model on my dataset, I see that some of the coefficients are significant and this means that they are time dependent. I am not sure whether they are or not time dependent. I hope this explains :s